# Searching words in two column

Tags: mysql, pdo

i am working on a search script and this is

my php code:

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9çğıöüş]/", " ", $_POST['query']);

$search_param = '%'.$search_string.'%';
// Do Search
$result_array = search_by_name($search_param); //functions
```

and i have a query like this:

```
SELECT user_id AS id,  
       user_firstname AS firstname,  
       user_lastname AS lastname,  
       user_profile_picture AS picture  
FROM users WHERE  
       user_firstname LIKE :user_firstname  
    OR user_lastname LIKE :user_lastname  

 $result->bindParam(':user_firstname', $search_param, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $result->bindParam(':user_lastname', $search_param, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

when you write a word, this query finds it in user_firstname column or in user_lastname columns.
For instance,

```
 `user_firstname    user_lastname
  --------------    -------------
  james             wood
  jimmy             james
  george            wood
```

in this case if I write 'james' to the search area, I'll find 'james wood' and 'jimmy james' however, if I write 'james wood'  I won't find anything because i am searching it in user_firstname column or user_lastname colum which does not contain 'james wood'.

what I want to do is to be able to search full names and get the results. how do I do this?

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an new column something like user_first_last_name. put the first names and last names together. And search from that column.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Reading your rewritten question, this becomes a php problem. Assuming that names to be searched for are always entered "first last" (not "last first"), you should check the input and if it has two or more words, split the input at the first space into two variables: `user_firstname` and `user_lastname`. If the input has only one word, put it into a variable `user_eithername`.
Then your SQL would be:

```
SELECT user_id AS id,  
       user_firstname AS firstname,  
       user_lastname AS lastname,  
       user_profile_picture AS picture  
FROM users WHERE  
       ( user_firstname LIKE :user_firstname  
    AND user_lastname  LIKE :user_lastname )
    OR user_firstname LIKE :user_eithername  
    OR user_lastname  LIKE :user_eithername
```

This would mostly work, but there will still be some problems - searching for a last name (only) of "van Gogh" would be interpreted as `firstname=van` `lastname=Gogh` which is not correct. The user would have to just enter "Gogh", but then the `Like 'Gogh%'` would still not match "van Gogh". It is difficult to provide a complete solution without knowing more of your requirements, data, user base etc.

Comment: actually there is only one string to be searched. it is 'james wood'. if i write 'james wood' it will search in user_firstname or user_lastname. i need to search it in user_firstname + user_lastname